# Restricting the zero in the first position in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jsp

Here I am using AngularJS and jQuery and Javascript.

this is working fine in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o1hdh8rw/1/)

```
 $('input#myId').keypress(function(e){ 
           if (this.value.length == 0 && e.which == 48 ){
              return false;
           }
        });
```

When I try to use the same in the JSP page it is not working.. how can I intigrate this jquery in my JSP.

I have tried to use this code in

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('input#myId').keypress(function(e){ 
     if (this.value.length == 0 && e.which == 48 ){
       return false;
      }
  });
</script>
```

But it is not working
UPDATE:-I want to restrict . also at the first position,How can I restrict dot also

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: I am not getting any errors in console

Comment: is your script tag below your input?

Comment: Are you sure your javascript is executed after your myId input is rendered in the page? TRy `console.log(document.getElementById('myId'))`in top of your snippet

Comment: You probably doesn't bind the event for some reason... Try at least to wrap it in document ready handler. That's said, better would be to use an input of type number with min attribute of 1. And be aware than user can still paste any value with leading 0 using your code.

Comment: @JoeLissner the script is top on input field

Comment: It should be below it.

Comment: @JoeLissner you are correct... thanks

Answer (score 1):

I see your method is not initialized.

Use your code inside $(document).ready(function(){});

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input#myId').keypress(function(e){ 
     if (this.value.length == 0 && e.which == 48 ){
       return false;
      }
  });
});
</script>
```